# Nested loops to CUDA

Tags: c, loops, indexing, cuda

I want to port my c code to CUDA. The main computational part contains 3 for nested loops:

```
for (int i=0; i< Nx;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<Ncontains[i];j++){
    for (int k=0;k< totalVoxels;k++){
          .......
   }
  }
}
```

How can I translate that to my CUDA kernel? With two for loops I could do something like:

```
int n= blockIdy.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int i= blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

But how can I initially this get running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ways you can do it, One of them is:

```
for (int i=blockIdx.x; i< Nx; i += gridDim.x){
  for (int j=threadIdx.y; j<Ncontains[i]; j+= blockDim.y){
    for (int k=threadIdx.x; k< totalVoxels; k += blockDim.x){
          .......
   }
  }
}
```

The above you would call:

```
// nx,ny block dimensions
kernel <<< dim3(nBlocks), dim3(nx, ny) >>> (...);
```

Comment: and doing this way, I would have to call the kernel that way?-> kernel <<< Nblock,Nthreads_per_block >>> for example, I could say kernel<<<20,16>>>? Is there a cleaner and more efficient way to call that kernel? Sorry, I am pretty new ... and thank you to Anycorn.

Comment: @Man see update.  Also note that parallelizaton strong depends on your particular case.  Above is *just* example

Comment: I know it could not really improve in the first instance, however my first goal is to get it correctly running on the GPU. Optimization will come in the second stage. I'll first try to understand your answer and then I will try to improve the speed up. Do you know where I could learn all these "tricks" ? I've read almost all the NVIDIA manuals and books but it always related to a matrix and not to loops or algorithms...

Comment: I was wandering if the last for loop was correct:for (int k=threadIdx.x; k< totalVoxels; k += blockDim.y){   Should be k +=blockDim.x instead?